# Como pegar todas as chamadas de função de um script php?

Tags: php, funções

**Exemplo:**

- index.php

  ```
  <?php
  foo();
  bar();

  print_r(getCalledFunctions(__FILE__));
  ```

Print:

```
array
    0 => 'foo'
    1 => 'bar'
```

**Pergunta:**

Alguem pode me retornar a função getCalledFunctions?

Comment: Isso é uma pergunta? Não estou a perceber...

Comment: Sim, quero a função getCalledFunctions...

Comment: Ah... Acho que não há nenhuma forma de fazer isso. Pelo menos que me lembre.

Comment: Tem na comunidade StackOverflow em inglês, só não sei se é o que procura. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881588/get-a-called-functions-list-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução razoável demonstrada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881588/get-a-called-functions-list-in-php) do Stack Overflow é cria uma classe chamada `Debug` e incluí-la acima de qualquer arquivo que você deseja depurar.

```
class Debug {
    private static $calls;

    public static function log($message = null)
    {
        if(!is_array(self::$calls))
            self::$calls = array();

        $call = debug_backtrace(false);
        $call = (isset($call[1]))?$call[1]:$call[0];

        $call['message'] = $message;
        array_push(self::$calls, $call);
    }
}
```

Invoque o método *Debug::log()* sempre que precisar na primeira linha do corpo de suas funções.

E por fim imprima como desejar as informações da propriedade *Debug::calls*.

Comment: Putz... eu terei que colocar dentro de todas as funções???